# Akka Http Server - How to have route respond with byte array binary response

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Using the high level routing api,

How does one complete() a request within a route using a byte array binary response,

For example:

```
complete(HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/octet-stream`, byteArray)
```

?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Strict`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity$$Strict.html) entity type:

```
import akka.util.ByteString
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpResponse, MediaTypes,HttpEntity}

val byteArray : Array[Byte] = ???

val body = ByteString(byteArray)

val entity = HttpEntity.Strict(MediaTypes.`application/octet-stream`, body)

val httpResponse = HttpResponse(entity = entity)

complete(httpResponse)
```